# How to pass a function from another class as parameter?

Tags: c++

I want to pass a function from another class as parameter in my current class. I'm trying to do something like this (I siplified the code, so you still can get the idea):

`B class:`

```
bool B::myCmpFunc(int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
}

vector<int> B::sort(bool (*cmp)(int a, int b)) {
    vector<int> elems = getElems();
    for (int i = 0; i < elems.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < elems.size(); j++) {
            if ((*cmp)(elems[i], elems[j])) {
                int aux = elems[i];
                elems[i] = elems[j];
                elems[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    return elems;
}
```

And I try to call this sort function from `A class`:

```
B b;
auto sortedElems = b.sort(&b.myCmpFunc);
```

The problem is I get this error when I try to pass **&b.myCmpFunc** as parameter in `A class`:

> Error C2276   '&': illegal operation on bound member function
>   expression

I also tried another things, like passing the function as `b.myCmpFunct`, `B::myCmpFunc`, `&B::myCmpFunc`, but I still got errors.

Comment: Is `B::myCmpFunc` a `static` member function?

Comment: No, it is not a static member function.

Comment: Did you try searching for the exact error message?

Comment: Don't you get pissed when minimal research hasn't been conducted and no [mcve] has been provided, yet someone **still** insists on balancing the vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `class` function (non static function inside a class), you need to pass `this`/the instance of the class around, so the compiler can pass `this`/the instance of the object to the function, when it invokes it.

You can:

1. Make your function `static`. `static` functions inside a class don't use `this` / the object instance, so their pointers are normal.

```
static bool B::myCmpFunc(int a, int b) {}
b.sort(&b.myCmpFunc);
// or
b.sort(&B::myCmpFunc);
```

2. You can refactor your function to use `std::function` and bind `this` with object pointer using `std::bind`.

```
vector<int> B::sort(std::function<bool(int a, int b)> cmp) {
        ... no changes ...
}
b.sort(std::bind(&B::myCmpFunc, &b, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

3. Refactor your function to take only `B` class functions.

```
vector<int> B::sort(bool (B::*cmp)(int a, int b)) {
       ...
       (this->*cmp)(...);
       ...
}
b.sort(&B::myCmpFunc);
```

4. Use a lambda.

```
b.sort([](int a, int b) -> bool { return a < b; });
// really or
b.sort([&b](int a, int b) -> bool { return b.myCmpFunc(a, b); });
```

5. and many more (ex. template).

As the member function `B::myCmpFunc` doesn't seem to use `this` pointer nor object members, I would go with declaring it `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You mix up pointers to ordinary functions and pointer to member functions. Those are different concepts, that are worth understanding at some point. What you can do is to make the comparison function a `static` and then pass a pointer to it like this:

```
auto sortedElems = b.sort(&B::myCmpFunc);
```

Otherwise, you can implement `myCmpFunc` as a *free* function, i.e., not bound to a class. Then pass it as

```
auto sortedElems = b.sort(&myFreeCmpFunc);
```

In any case, it doesn't make much sense to have a member function `myCmpFunc` that has no dependency on the state of its object. Making it a free function increases encapsulation and makes the comparison function reusable (apart from the fact that you could also use a `std::greater<>{}` function object instead.

Comment: Makeing the function `static` solved the problem. Thank you!